# how to put background color fixed in my app xamarin forms and avoid that change on any device

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

i'm tryna put a background color  in light mode on visual studio with even i put this in info.plist iOS but i don't want that even the device have the dark mode  affect my app

```
<key>UIUserInterfaceStyle</key>
 <string>Light</string>

and this code is c# 

AppCompatDelegate.DefaultNightMode = AppCompatDelegate.ModeNightNo;
```

Comment: More suggestions [here](https://montemagno.com/opt-out-of-dark-mode-on-ios-android-uwp-and-macos/). You can also set whatever colors you want, by creating a [style per element](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/styles/xaml/implicit) (Label, Button, etc.) in `App.xaml.cs`.

Comment: Can I confirm if you want to change app theme? If yes, please refer to [Theme a Xamarin.Forms Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/theming/theming).